# TurtleBot Pointcloud in Rviz

Tags: rviz, turtlebot, xtion, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SSH'ing into my TurtleBot and running it on there is really laggy, and someone told me that this is because of the high bandwidth requirements of a graphics heavy app like Rviz. He said I should run Rviz locally and have it receive its position and point cloud data from the turtlebot. Any idea how i would go about doing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71545/turtlebot-pointcloud-in-rviz/) by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2013-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-14**:
@llSourcell  don't use # in your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should first configure your environment variables on your both computer, Turtlebot and workstation.
Put Turtlebot computer as master on both station with:
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://turtlebot_ip like:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.101:11311
```

In the workstation do also:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=workstation_ip
```

In your Turtlebot laptop:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=turtlebot_ip
export ROS_IP=turtleot_ip
```

even local-host should be defined explicitly.

Check those links for more documentation:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

---

Originally posted by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) with karma: 411 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2